# What's the section of code (or loop) which retrieves the Page title and description?

Tags: pages

What's the code of the loop which retrieves the Page title and description?

I checked the code inside page.php of the Starkers theme (I guess is the same as the TwentyTen theme):

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
     <?php } else { ?> 
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
     <?php } ?>    

      <?php the_content(); ?>
      <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '' ) ); ?>
      <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), '', '' ); ?>

    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
```

I looks identical to the loop which retrieves the main (blog) posts.

What's the difference?

Which is the part which retrieves the title and content of the current Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual - [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) and [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content). Posts page and *a PAGE page* are different in amount and type of content, but mechanics of [main Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) are essentially same.

Comment: If they are the same how can I display the main posts loop under the loop of the page?

Comment: @janoChen strictly speaking you can't. You can create secondary Loop (`get_posts()` or separate `WP_Query` object) that will mimic that. There is no difference in result, but there is difference in logic and mechanics. Basically main Loop controls what post/page/archive/whatever **is**. Secondary Loops can be whatever you want (as long as they don't mess with and break main Loop).